# Are pigtail neutral wire and plug-on neutral breakers interchangeable?

Tags: electrical

I have about 5 breakers which keep tripping off and an electrician said I need to replace those breakers. The Cat. No. is CHFAFGF120, and seems now there’s a new version with Cat. No. CHFN120DF. I found there’s another one CHFP120DF much cheaper and seems the difference is N is pigtail and P is plug-on. I’m wondering, are they interchangeable? If not, is CHFN120DF the only one we can use? How can we look if there’s any cheaper alternatives?

Comment: Depends on your panel. Model #?  Picture?

Answer (score 12):

No.

*Plug-on neutral* breakers require a service panel equipped with plug-on neutral bars.  This is a recent development.

Your panel labeling will indicate whether it accepts plug-on neutral breakers, by including them in the list of breaker types it supports.  If it does not include any, it doesn't support them.

Generally you can't cross brands with breakers.  You can if a competitor breaker is *UL Classified* specifically for your panel, so that is Eaton CHQ, CL, and Siemens QD only.  None of these will fit a CH panel.

Eaton is usually quite competitive with CH breaker pricing. If you are seeing out-of-line pricing, that is probably due to the vendors you are using - mail order is the worst possible choice for electrical equipment, as prices are always bizarre, even NOT during supply chain shortages as we have now.

However I think you're about to waste $200+ and will find this does not fix it. I find it extremely unlikely 5 breakers would fail all at once.  This is a wiring or equipment problem.  You should *really* work the failure tree on this one.  Start by determining whether the breaker is tripping due to an *arc* fault, a *ground* fault or an *overcurrent* fault.

It could be something as easy as pilot error (can't run all that stuff at once) or wiring or an appliance arcing that is not on any of those circuits.

Comment: I’m not sure if this matters but we have been able to untrip the breakers by manually switch them back and we will be able to use the electric equipments for a certain time. And then we don’t know when, they will tripped again…

Comment: @Ruyue-ElevenMerlington -- can you pull the fault codes from the breakers?

Comment: Fault codes? Please enlighten us.

Comment: AFCI/GFCI breakers commonly have diagnostic indicators to show what type of trip they have had. Eaton says for the family this is part of: *AF/GF breakers are equipped with a red diagnostic LED that blinks a repeating pattern, from 1 to 6 blinks, indicating the cause of trip. This pattern is the “trip code”. The LED will blink the trip code for 30 iterations after being turned back on.*

Comment: If they were indicating AFCI trip, we could guess that they are tripping when something on a 6th, unrelated circuit is switched on/cycles on.  But we need to know the indication to be sure of that.